# Up to date, JPA compliant GenericDAO Implementation

Tags: spring, jpa, dao, genericdao

I read this article:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-genericdao.html

several times and believe I understand what it is saying.  However, it is 4 years old and I have a JPA compliant Java application to contend with.  In addition, I see that there is a JPATemplate in Spring that has some good functionality, but the Spring documentation says it is already deprecated!

Can anybody point me to a solid, modern, JPA compliant, Spring based, working example of a GenericDAOImpl that proxies an Interface to provide generic finder execution?

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays JPA 2 in itself has become a decent implementation of a DAO layer since its responsibility (or contract if you wish) is the same as for the traditional "crafted" DAO, that is an isolation of a business logic from a storage mechanism. An important implication out of this is that you may need an explicit DAO only when working with non-DBMS storages like spreadsheet files, web-services, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a generic DAO mixing different approaches that I shared on SO in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239754/approach-for-a-generic-ddd-repository-with-jpa-spring-does-it-look-wrong). I use these 2 approaches: [DDD: The Generic Repository](http://codebetter.com/blogs/gregyoung/archive/2009/01/16/ddd-the-generic-repository.aspx) and [JPA implementation patterns: Data Access Objects](http://blog.xebia.com/2009/03/09/jpa-implementation-patterns-data-access-objects/).

Please feel free to comment/edit if you think it can be improved.

Comment: Its a start -- thanks for the help.  For me, an important aspect of it is the ability for a single DAO implementation to execute any named query via a set of DAO interfaces.  The IBM article uses AOP, but I am working on an approach that uses a proxy object to implement the defined interfaces without AOP.